# How to change frame per second (FPS) while using `cv2` when converting video to frames?

Tags: python, opencv

Currently I am using `2017_08_31_0121.mp4` as my video which is a 21-second long video and once I break it into frames, I get 504 frames. This means that frame per second is set to 24. I want to change the number of frames but I do not know which part of the following code is responsible for setting frame per second.

**Questions:**

1. I thought for a long time that the default FPS is 25 but now I have 24, can you please let me know where the default FPS is set and what it is?
2. If I want to use a custom FPS let's say 10, how can I modify the following code to do it?

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/2017_08_31_0121.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
while success:
  if count<10:
    id = f'00{count}'
  elif count < 100:
    id = f'0{count}'
  else:
    id = count
  cv2.imwrite(f"./new_frames/frame{id}.jpg", image)    # save frame as JPEG file      
  success, image = vidcap.read()
  count += 1
```

Comment: nonsensical requirement. OpenCV will read the video as quickly as possible. you will get exactly those frames that are in the file. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Btw, you can achieve zero-padding more simply with `f"./new_frames/frame{id:03d}.jpg"`

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: "OpenCV will read the video as quickly as possible". Thank you. I was not aware of that. Which one reads it `cv2.VideoCapture` or `vidcap.read()`. I am asking this since I do not want to completely read it and I want to extract (3 or 5) frames out of each second of my original file. That is my final goal.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: Oh. God. Thank you. I did not know that by just adding zero before the integer I can pad with zero. Can you please provide me with a Python documentation that explains this because I have been using `{:nd}` for a long time but did not know adding a zero before the natural number does that.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: specifically, I want to extract 3 or 5 frames out of each second without reading all the frames.

Comment: Take a step back from frames per second and skipping and jumping for a moment and try and say simply what you are trying to do so we can help you better. Are you trying to shorten a video for some reason? Or speed it up? What? Why? Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: I have a dataset of videos and wanted to apply semantic segmentation to videos. I could not:) Then I decided to break each video to frames and then apply semantic segmentation on frames. By the above code, I change videos to frames. The problem is that for a 21-second long video I get 504 frames which is too many since I have more than 1000 videos with more than 2 minutes long. Now, I want to get less frames per second than the actual video to have less saved frames on my disc for training set. I do not know how to alter my code to get less saved frames. Hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to know how "video" works.

Video consists of keyframes and P/B-frames. Keyframes are complete images on their own. To decode a P/B-frame, preceding frames need to be decoded first. Some video files consist only of keyframes ("intra"). Some video files consist of a keyframe every ~0.1-10 seconds, and only P/B-frames in between.

You can skip around in a video, but you can only directly skip to keyframes. If you wanted to skip to a non-keyframe, you'd have to first skip to the preceding keyframe, and then decode each following frame, until you're at the destination.

Ideas I would recommend that you **not** follow:

- `ffmpeg -i INPUT -r 3 OUTPUT` would read the entire video, and duplicate/drop frames as needed to achieve 3 frames per second, while maintaining the "speed" of what you see in the video. It would **also** have to re-encode the result. That's only a sensible option if you need to read the same video repeatedly in that frame rate.
- Involving *GNU Parallel* with ffmpeg would be pointless because ffmpeg itself runs its decoding and encoding in parallel (for most codecs), using all available CPU.

Here is what you **can** do:

use the methods `grab` and `retrieve` of VideoCapture. Call `grab` repeatedly. This does the minimal work to decode a frame and advance in the video. Call `retrieve` for the frame you actually want. This does the rest of the work and it will give you that frame as an array.

You would have to check the video's `fps` value using `vidcap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)` and then count along and decide if you only need to grab, or both grab and retrieve.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/2017_08_31_0121.mp4')
assert vidcap.isOpened()

fps_in = vidcap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
fps_out = 3

index_in = -1
index_out = -1

while True:
    success = vidcap.grab()
    if not success: break
    index_in += 1

    out_due = int(index_in / fps_in * fps_out)
    if out_due > index_out:
        success, frame = vidcap.retrieve()
        if not success: break
        index_out += 1

        # do something with `frame`
```

Comment: You are right - I am deleting my suggestions.

Comment: as for "default" fps, that doesn't exist. videos come in various frame rates. europe likes 25 fps. america likes 23.976 fps. fractions and multiples of those exist. some videos even have no fixed frame rate, meaning the time between frames can vary.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: thank you so much for your enlightening answer. As I am not familiar with videos can you please let me know what are P/B-frames? and P/B stands for what? Also, can you please let me know for a given video how I can extract keyframes?

Comment: opencv can't tell what type a frame is, nor can it tell where keyframes are. it's a library for computer vision, not for handling video files. look into "PyAV" instead (also ffmpeg). -- frames, their names, and meanings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types